# Grep for word and line before match

Tags: regex, linux, bash, awk, grep

I have a text log file which contains multiple entries like this:

```
Processing input.jpg (323 of 500)...
Detecting matches in region 1...
Detecting matches in region 2...
Detecting matches in region 3...
Detecting matches in region 4...
Detecting matches in region (n)...
...
NOT ENOUGH MATCHES - FULL FILE OUTPUT
Processing input1.jpg (324 of 500)...
```

I want to grep the file to match each instance where the sequence FULL FILE appears and then get the name of the file that generated that result - i.e. find the line starting Processing before each FULL FILE match.

How can I do this with grep or another tool like sed or awk?

So far I am able to match each instance where FULL FILE is found in the log and count them:

```
cat output.txt | grep "FULL FILE" | wc -l
```

but I need to get the preceding file name from the log file now for each match.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming no spaces in file names, `awk` would be up to it

```
awk '/^Processing/{file=$2};/FULL FILE OUTPUT$/{print file}' output.txt
```

Comment: You do not need the `;` after `}`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use sed as follows:

```
sed -n '/FULL FILE OUTPUT/{ N;s/.*\nProcessing \(.*\) (.*).*/\1/p}' my_file
```

Matches any line with `FULL FILE OUTPUT`, then take the next line after the match and find your file name.

Comment: I don't think this works; specifically, he wants the "Processing" line **before** the "FULL FILE OUTPUT" line; the one after it is for the next file

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do it with `grep` like you asked....

First extract just the lines starting `Processing` and the lines containing `FULL FILE` but weed out all the other stuff that we don't know the length of. This way the filename you want will be on the line immediately before the `FULL FILE` line.

```
egrep "^Processing|FULL FILE" output.txt
```

Now do another `grep`, but get the line before "FULL FILE" using `-B1`, then remove the `FULL FILE` lines

```
egrep "^Processing|FULL FILE” output.txt | grep -B1 "FULL FILE" | grep "^Processing“
```